# Circular Dependency Open-Close Balance

Tags: powerbi, dependencies, dax, visualization, measure

I am trying to generate a Balance, but I get a circular dependency.
The Initial Balance (the day the report is consulted will be Day 1) is the sum (Table1[Qty]). Then from second day on, it will be Final Balance
Sales, Sum Table2[Qty Sold] of the corresponding day
Final Balance, it will be Initial Balance - Sales.

Also, the visual is a matrix and it should be possible to get to see the values of Initial Balance, Sales and Final Balance per item.

What im looking for:
[image]

Dax:

```
 Inventory = Calculate(
    SUM ( 'Table1'[Qty] ))





Sales = Calculate(
    SUM ( 'Table2'[Qty Sold] )
)



Initial Balance = IF(
    MAX(Dates[Date]) = TODAY(),
    [Inventory],
    CALCULATE([FinalBalance],PREVIOUSDAY(Dates[Date])
))



Final Balance = IF(
    MAX(Dates[Date]) = TODAY(),
   [Inventory] - [Sales],
   [Initial Balance] - [Sales]
)
```

[image]
**Is there any way to work with this? Because, in the end, one measure depends on the other.**

Answer (score 0):

Just a suggestion, maybe try removing the calculate around Inventory and Sales measures and just use SUM() directly. If you want to use calculate(), then you should use ALLEXCEPT(Date column) in the filter part of CALCULATE.

Answer (score 0):

Think about it this way:

- Final Balance = SUM QTY (to date) - SUM Sales (to date)
- Initial Balance = SUM QTY (to date) - SUM Sales (up to excluding to date)

Try:

```
Initial Balance = 
  var thisDate = MAX(Dates[Date])
  var vSales =
    CALCUALTE(
      [Sales],
      REMOVEFILTERS(Dates),
      'Table2'[Date] < thisDate // note <
    )
  return [Inventory] - vSales



Final Balance = 
  var thisDate = MAX(Dates[Date])
  var vSales =
    CALCUALTE(
      [Sales],
      REMOVEFILTERS(Dates),
      'Table2'[Date] <= thisDate // note <=
    )
  return [Inventory] - vSales
```

Both measures above are independent of each other.